# An answer where I invested time was suddenly deleted without feedback

Tags: discussion, status-completed, deleted-answers, specific-answer

My answer to [a question about Xamarin.Forms TabBar's Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64892392/xamarin-forms-shell-how-to-get-the-bottom-tabbar-height/64893831#64893831) was deleted without a single comment even though, as I see it, provided a valuable alternative solution for the OP.

Why did this happen?

Comment: Looking at the timeline, i'd guess the low quality flag attracted the attention of a mod who was knowledgeable of the subject matter. it had 4 downvotes at the time, so it was capable of being delete voted by anyone with enough rep.

Comment: Given that it seems like a pretty well written answer with plenty of documentation (code, links to support, etc) i'd guess quality isn't the reason it was deleted. At 4 downvotes I'd question whether or not it was actually "valuable", however I'm not familiar with the subject matter and therefore can't judge

Comment: Just wait and see, you've come to the right place. You could edit it, but that won't send it to a queue to be reviewed.

Comment: The speculation that the answer was flagged as "very low quality" is correct. A moderator reviewed that flag and chose to delete the answer. However, it is not immediately clear to me why the moderator who originally handled this came to the decision that they did. As such, I've asked them to weigh in here, when they are available. So please be patient; we are looking into this. As has been noted, you've done the right thing by coming to Meta and asking for support. Let me apologize for the confusing experience that you've had, regardless of how this is ultimately resolved.

Comment: @Deczaloth While getting feeback is nice, moderators themselves rarely have enough time to leave customized feedback to every single action they take because it slow down the great work they do handling flags. As for the users who flagged it as "Low Quality" initially - the problem you will see is leaving comments actually triggers some users to lash out (retaliatory downvotes, abusing namecalling, etc).  So some users end up not commenting just to protect themselves.

Comment: The over-the-top flameouts I see semiregularly when someone explains so much as a downvote, theirs or someone else's, conditions folks to NOT explain voting. I'll explain a problem to a user once. Future explanations depends a lot on the response I get.

Comment: @Deczaloth sir this is not deleted??

Comment: @KUMAR It was when he posted the question. It has since been *undeleted*. See the answer below, by Samuel Liew.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sorry, I made a mistake there and have now undeleted the answer.